# Animating lights on and off that have noise modifier

Tags: animation

I have a point light that is using the noise modifier to give me random intensity, I would like to animate the light on and off at a certain point is there a way to do this without affecting the noise modifier settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keyframe its visibility in the *Outliner*:

[image]

In Cycles you can give a material to your light, so you can mix the *Emission* with a *Transparent* for example, and if you keyframe the factor of the *Mix Shader* you can turn the light on and off (or gradually fade out and fade in):

[image]

Comment: True, I thought of that, but the thing is the light is shared so it’s used in 15 other lights throughout the comp.